# Where is MS Reports Log files located and accessed?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have two MS Reports with each their own dataset.

The first one works but the other does not fill anything in it's table. When I debug the dataset, just before showing the Report, it's fill, and I did the same setup as with the first report.

I get no errors og other input.. The table just not show any rows at all.

Is their any log files that can tell me something and if so, where can I find them? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check 3 things:

1. See that the  dataset binded are the same (that u r filling)
2. is the report Showing the formatted headers(table and column header) this means that table format is ok.
3. if you want you can check report .rdlc file (it is xml base file generated for the report)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
1) I have a dataset on the form and a bindingSource. And a dataset on the report. I fill the first dataset, I checked in the debugger with "DataSet Visualizer" and it shows some fine tables.
2) Yes it does. I'm only missing the rows below.
3) I'll go check, but not sure what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

The report server log file location can be found in the registry:

- HKLM

  - Software

    - Microsoft

      - Microsoft SQL Server

        - {Report Server Instance Name, mine is MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER}

          - CPE

The log file location is the data value associated with the **ErrorDumpDir** key.

When previewing in report designer any error messages will be displayed in the preview tab. Sounds like you may have a different problem that won't be reported in the logs. Double-check that the query returns data. You may want to use [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) (assuming your database is SQL Server) to debug queries executed against the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found my ERRORLOG's now. I have Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. How do I open this error? Am I just being naiv, or is there something in it that is actually readable and useable? :)

Comment: ERRORLOG files are text, but these are for the SQL Server database instance. I thought you were looking for reporting services log files?

Comment: Yes i'm looking for log files for reporting services. I have no clue why this tables wan't show it's rows. I tryed it all over and over and is running out of idears. :/

Comment: The reporting services log files are in the report server instance directory, which identified from the registry as described above. Have you used profiler to check the query?

Comment: My bad, first I tryed to open the ERRORLOG file in SQL Server Manager. It opens in Notepad. 
I get an Access is denied when I try to open log_109.trc file in SQL Server Profiler. I hope I can find something in these files, but if I don't big thanks for pointing me to these files :)

Comment: The .trc files are not log files, they are profiler trace files created by the SQL Server instance. Sounds like you're still in the SQL Server database directory...find the report server folder and go from there. Debugging report queries with profiler will get you the best info needed to address the problem at this point.

Comment: I'm here, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.ADB_SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log..

Comment: Oh you mean I have to grab my querry while debugging and paste it in the SQL Server Profiler, and see what I tells me. Sorry for being slow, working with profilers is new for me. I will read up on it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6198/discussion-between-beargle-and-radbyx)