# Visual Studio RDLC Log File Location?

Tags: visual-studio, logging, reporting, rdlc

Upon loading a subreport, I receive the message **Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'subPerformanceCover', located at: PerformanceCover.rdlc. Please check the log files for more information.**

Where is the log file located?

Comment: Interesting that, after doing a google search, no one seems to know where these mysterious log files are located.  If they are supposed to be SQL Server Log files, there is nothing in them for me and the error message should say something like SQL Errorlog if it were them to be less ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I went through a similar issue (which is how I found your question).  As best as I can tell the reference to the logs is misleading, although I have a theory which would explain how they might be there, but not for the way I was using them.

See this answer for the registry location https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658088/12085

The linked answer is more focused on RDL than RDLC. For example, I didn't have a report instance name section because it's client reporting rather than server.  But I did search for CPE in the registry and found a location.  It wasn't helpful and examining all of those logs determined that they are just SQL Server's logs and nothing to do with my report.

While they weren't helpful for me, your mileage may vary... I was using objects as my data source, so I could imagine there might be a scenario where those logs do get populated if you had T-SQL in them.

Answer (score -1):

If you do a search of your computer (I use Search Everything) for files starting with "ReportServerService", you should be able find them.  I also did a search for folders called "LogFiles".  On my machine I found two repositories of log files.

For SQL Server 2012,  you will find the SSRS log files located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.[Instance Name]\Reporting Services\LogFiles.

I also had SQL Server 2005 running at one point, and the log files for there were found in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\LogFiles\